# How to sort the API data according to date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api

I am successfully retrieving the information from an API call but I was required to sort the data according to dates. Everything is perfect but when retrieving the data from API the data is not according to dates.

```
function retrieveInfo(container){
var user = userLoggedIn;
console.log(user);
container.html();
fetchNext5Days();

 dates.forEach(async (date) =>{
    url= API ;
    await fetch(url).then(async(res)=>{
        return await res.json();
    }).then(async (data)=>{
        data.centers.forEach(async (center)=>{
                var html = await createInfoFeedHtml(center);
                container.append(html);
        });
    })
    
})}
```

fetchNext5days function

```
async function fetchNext5Days(){
let today = moment();
for(let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ ){
    let dateString = today.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    dates.push(dateString);
    console.log(dates)
    today.add(1, 'day');
}
}
```

This function is also outputting the dates correctly from ascending to descending order.
10-05-2021 11-05-2021 12-05-2021 13-05-2021 14-05-2021

The difference is in outputting the data.
[image: Dates are not in order]

```
function createInfoFeedHtml(center)
{
return `
<tr class= "dark-row">
<td>${center.sessions[0].date}</td>
<td >${center.name}</td>
<td> ${center.address}</td>
<td>${center.sessions[0].vaccine}</td>     
<td>${center.sessions[0].min_age_limit}</td> 
<td>${center.sessions[0].available_capacity}</td>                           
</tr>
        `
}
```

The data from the api is made into table rows and inserted into.

**Pug file**

```
block content    

.container
    .row
        .table-responsive.table-bordered.movie-table
            table.table.movie-table
                thead
                    tr.movie-table-head
                        th Date
                        th Name
                        th Address 
                        th Vaccine
                        th Age
                        th Availability
                    tbody
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Comment: But i cannot fetch the data according to date.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What is the problem, can't you just sort the dates before sending it or after receiving it? 
If you can make a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I am having the dates in an array are sorted but while fetching and displaying on the webpage the dates are in jumbled order, not the way in which I need them.

Comment: Only while fetching the info the dates are not in sequence.

Comment: If you can, it would be probably better to sort server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your async function is returning data at different intervals so your date order is getting lost. Just write the elements to the page and sort them on their dates as they get written. I modified your createInfoFeedHtml function to put a timestamp on the divs

```
dates.forEach(async (date) =>{
    ....
    }).then(async (data)=>{
        data.centers.forEach(async (center)=>{
                var html = await createInfoFeedHtml(center);
                container.append(html);
                sortTableOnDate(container); 
                
        });
    })
    
})}
    
function createInfoFeedHtml(center)
{
 var timestamp = new Date(center.sessions[0].date).getTime();
return `
<tr class= "dark-row sortable"  data-timestamp='${timestamp}'>
<td>${center.sessions[0].date}</td>
<td >${center.name}</td>
<td> ${center.address}</td>
<td>${center.sessions[0].vaccine}</td>     
<td>${center.sessions[0].min_age_limit}</td> 
<td>${center.sessions[0].available_capacity}</td>                           
</tr>
        `
}

//sortTableOnDate will gather a set of divs and sort them ascendingly from their timestamp attribute
function sortTableOnDate(container) {
  $(container).find('.sortable').sort(function(a, b) {
     return +a.getAttribute('data-timestamp') - +b.getAttribute('data-timestamp');
  })
  .appendTo($(container));
}
```

Comment: But i am returning a table row in createInfoFeedHtml function

Comment: Can you post the code for that function? And the HTML where it gets inserted?

Comment: Try that. I made a change in each block of code

Comment: Can you tell where it's choking? It's hard to troubleshoot it without data

Comment: No change, it is as before.